# To "strum strings" and "hit keys"

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use a verb right next to its corresponding noun in this specific context?

**I strum strings and hit keys for a living.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would it be wrong? Which rules do you have in mind that would prohibit it? What alternatives are you considering, and what makes you think they are superior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with that.

However, your title does have a mistake - to "strum string" is wrong, you can only put the verb directly there when it is plural.

> To strum strings (✓)
>
> To strum a string (✓)
>
> To strum string (✓ it is grammatically correct, but does not means what you mean - I assume you are talking about playing a guitar or similar, but this comes across as a piece of string stretched across the room, which you are strumming)